# Can't override property of the base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to create a new class base on a class, and I want to override a property in the base class for remove [Required]. But instead of overriding, it created a new property with the same name. So what wrong, and how to fix it.

```
namespace admin.models
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        [Required]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewClass : BaseClass
    {
        public new string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to declare the property `virtual` or `abstract` in the base class, and `override` in the derived class. Base: `public virtual string id { get; set; }`, Derived: `public override string id { get; set; }`

Comment: In this case, I would use `abstract`

Comment: In your method add the line `var s = newClass.name;` and see what value is assigned to `s`.  What you're doing is fine.

Comment: @Archer But if he does `Baseclass b = newClass; var s = b.name;` he would get the base class version.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes he would, but that's not what he has.  Understanding the difference is most likely worth the OP knowing.

Comment: With that in mind, @jimmy, have a read of this -> **[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)**

Comment: @Archer in below example, newClass.name  = 'abcd',and when I post with name is null, ModelState.IsValid = false, what happen here

Comment: **[Have a look at this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kIn4x2)**.  It all depends on how you refer to the object instance.  Notice in that example I use the same object twice, but get different results because the functions take different type parameters.

Comment: @Archer: my purpose is to remove [Required], I post NewClass from a client. What will happen in this case?

Comment: You're being very, very vague.  If you want to remove the required attribute then remove it.  Deal with the actual problem, rather than creating others.  Sorry - can't help if I don't know what you're trying to do.  Put a variable and breakpoint in the method and look at the value, like I said in my first comment.

Comment: I would strongly suggest not using inheritance here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the method/property as `virtual` if you want to make it possible to override it. Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) for more info. Then use `override` to give a new implementation for the property.

```
namespace admin.models
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        [Required]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote because this is probably what the OP actually wants, but I can't upvote either because `You need to mark the method/property as virtual if you want to make it possible to override it` is not correct.